# Summary information for SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, olap

I'm working with a table that stores shift information for employees:

[image]

My goal is to create a new view or query that shows a summary for the information:

[image]

I'm thinking I need some type of OLAP query here, maybe a group by rollup...

I can get some of the information using a group by like this, but still need a way to combine it with the original table so it still shows additional information like name. Using SQL Server.

```
SELECT employee,[week], sum(regular), sum(overtime), 
       sum(regular_pay), sum(overtime_pay), sum(regular) + sum(overtime),
       sum(regular_pay) + sum(overtime_pay) FROM shift_details GROUP BY employee, [week]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, when creating formatted tables in SQL for reports, I've used a sorting method based on a new column.

E.G.

```
SELECT employee, week, regular, overtime, reg_pay, ot_pay, regular + overtime AS total_hours, reg_pay + ot_pay AS total_pay, 1 AS sort_by FROM shift_details
UNION ALL
SELECT employee,[week], sum(regular), sum(overtime), 
       sum(regular_pay), sum(overtime_pay), sum(regular) + sum(overtime),
       sum(regular_pay) + sum(overtime_pay), 2 AS sort_by FROM shift_details GROUP BY employee, [week]
ORDER BY employee, week, sort_by
```

... etc...

If you want to omit "sort_by", just wrap the query like this...

```
SELECT
  employee, week, regular, overtime, reg_pay, ot_pay, total_hours, total_pay
FROM
  (
    ... query above without the "ORDER" statement.
  ) AS inner_query
ORDER BY employee, week, sort_by
```